# Get height of left div (height: auto) and set it to the right div (overflow: scroll)

Tags: javascript, html, css, height

I have a problem and I don't know how to fix it. I want to have the same height for two div. The height of the left div has to be 'auto' and the right one must have the same height. The right div has 14 div inside it and they have to be scrollable.

Here is my code:

```css
#episodenbox {
    margin-top: 62px;
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: auto;
}

#titelbox {
    width: 960px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#titelbox p {
    margin-left: 6px;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
}

#thumbnail {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 12px;
    width: 632px;
    height: auto;
}

#thumbnail p {
    width: 616px;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 19px;
    margin: 0px 6px 6px 6px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#episodenimg {
    width: 620px;
    height: 349px;
    display: block;
    margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

#untertitelbox {
    margin-left: 12px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    float: left;
    width: 316px;
    height: 40px;
}

#untertitelbox p {
    margin-left: 6px;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 19px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 5px;
}

#episodenbox1 {
    margin-left: 12px;
    float: left;
    width: 316px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

#episode1 {
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 316px;
    height: 68px;
}

#episode1 img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 56px;
    display: block;
    margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

#episode1 p {
    margin-left: 112px;
    margin-top: -62px;
    color: #000000;
}

#episode2 {
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 316px;
    height: 68px;
}

#episode2 img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 56px;
    display: block;
    margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

#episode2 p {
    margin-left: 112px;
    margin-top: -62px;
    color: #000000;
}

#episode3 {
    margin-top: 3px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 316px;
    height: 68px;
}

#episode3 img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 56px;
    display: block;
    margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

#episode3 p {
    margin-left: 112px;
    margin-top: -62px;
    color: #000000;
}

#episode4 {
    margin-top: 3px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 316px;
    height: 68px;
}

#episode4 img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 56px;
    display: block;
    margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

#episode4 p {
    margin-left: 112px;
    margin-top: -62px;
    color: #000000;
}

#episode5 {
    margin-top: 3px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 316px;
    height: 68px;
}

#episode5 img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 56px;
    display: block;
    margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

#episode5 p {
    margin-left: 112px;
    margin-top: -62px;
    color: #000000;
}

#episode6 {
    margin-top: 3px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 316px;
    height: 68px;
}

#episode6 img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 56px;
    display: block;
    margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

#episode6 p {
    margin-left: 112px;
    margin-top: -62px;
    color: #000000;
}

#episode7 {
    margin-top: 3px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 316px;
    height: 68px;
}

#episode7 img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 56px;
    display: block;
    margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

#episode7 p {
    margin-left: 112px;
    margin-top: -62px;
    color: #000000;
}

#episode8 {
    margin-top: 3px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 316px;
    height: 68px;
}

#episode8 img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 56px;
    display: block;
    margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

#episode8 p {
    margin-left: 112px;
    margin-top: -62px;
    color: #000000;
}

#episode9 {
    margin-top: 3px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 316px;
    height: 68px;
}

#episode9 img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 56px;
    display: block;
    margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

#episode9 p {
    margin-left: 112px;
    margin-top: -62px;
    color: #000000;
}

#episode10 {
    margin-top: 3px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 316px;
    height: 68px;
}

#episode10 img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 56px;
    display: block;
    margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

#episode10 p {
    margin-left: 112px;
    margin-top: -62px;
    color: #000000;
}

#episode11 {
    margin-top: 3px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 316px;
    height: 68px;
}

#episode11 img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 56px;
    display: block;
    margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

#episode11 p {
    margin-left: 112px;
    margin-top: -62px;
    color: #000000;
}

#episode12 {
    margin-top: 3px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 316px;
    height: 68px;
}

#episode12 img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 56px;
    display: block;
    margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

#episode12 p {
    margin-left: 112px;
    margin-top: -62px;
    color: #000000;
}

#episode13 {
    margin-top: 3px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 316px;
    height: 68px;
}

#episode13 img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 56px;
    display: block;
    margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

#episode13 p {
    margin-left: 112px;
    margin-top: -62px;
    color: #000000;
}

#episode14 {
    margin-top: 3px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 316px;
    height: 68px;
}

#episode14 img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 56px;
    display: block;
    margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

#episode14 p {
    margin-left: 112px;
    margin-top: -62px;
    color: #000000;
}

#episode1:hover {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#episode2:hover {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#episode3:hover {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#episode4:hover {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#episode5:hover {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#episode6:hover {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#episode7:hover {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#episode8:hover {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#episode9:hover {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#episode10:hover {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#episode11:hover {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#episode12:hover {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#episode13:hover {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#episode14:hover {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}
```

```html
                        <div id="left">
                            <div id="titelbox">
                                <p>Episode 01: Begegnung</p>
                            </div>
                            <div id="thumbnail">
                                <img id="episodenimg" src="Episode%2001.png">
                                <p>Aus einem unterirdischen Forschungslabor bricht ein Mutant in Gestalt eines jungen M&auml;dchens aus und t&ouml;tet dabei 23 Sicherheitsleute. Die beiden Teenager Yuka und Kohta treffen am Strand auf den Mutanten, der durch den Streifschuss am Kopf aber offenbar sein Ged&auml;chtnis verloren hat.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="right">
                        <div id="untertitelbox">
                            <p>Andere Episoden:</p>
                        </div>
                            <div id="episodenbox1">
                                <a href="Episode%2002.html"><div id="episode2">
                                    <img src="Episode%2002.png">
                                    <p>Episode 02: Vernichtung</p>
                                </div></a>
                                <a href="Episode%2003.html"><div id="episode3">
                                    <img src="Episode%2003.png">
                                    <p>Episode 03: Im Innersten</p>
                                </div></a>
                                <a href="Episode%2004.html"><div id="episode4">
                                    <img src="Episode%2004.png">
                                    <p>Episode 04: Aufeinandertreffen</p>
                                </div></a>
                                <a href="Episode%2005.html"><div id="episode5">
                                    <img src="Episode%2005.png">
                                    <p>Episode 05: Empfang</p>
                                </div></a>
                                <a href="Episode%2006.html"><div id="episode6">
                                    <img src="Episode%2006.png">
                                    <p>Episode 06: Herzensw&auml;rme</p>
                                </div></a>
                                <a href="Episode%2007.html"><div id="episode7">
                                    <img src="Episode%2007.png">
                                    <p>Episode 07: Zuf&auml;llige Begegnung</p>
                                </div></a>
                                <a href="Episode%2008.html"><div id="episode8">
                                    <img src="Episode%2008.png">
                                    <p>Episode 08: Beginn</p>
                                </div></a>
                                <a href="Episode%2009.html"><div id="episode9">
                                    <img src="Episode%2009.png">
                                    <p>Episode 09: Sch&ouml;ne Erinnerung</p>
                                </div></a>
                                <a href="Episode%2010.html"><div id="episode10">
                                    <img src="Episode%2010.png">
                                    <p>Episode 10: S&auml;ugling</p>
                                </div></a>
                                <a href="Episode%2010,5.html"><div id="episode11">
                                    <img src="Episode%2010,5.png">
                                    <p>Episode 10,5: Regenschauer</p>
                                </div></a>
                                <a href="Episode%2011.html"><div id="episode12">
                                    <img src="Episode%2011.png">
                                    <p>Episode 11: Vermischung</p>
                                </div></a>
                                <a href="Episode%2012.html"><div id="episode13">
                                    <img src="Episode%2012.png">
                                    <p>Episode 12: Taumeln</p>
                                </div></a>
                                <a href="Episode%2013.html"><div id="episode14">
                                    <img src="Episode%2013.png">
                                    <p>Episode 13: Erleuchtung</p>
                                </div></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: couldn't you just provide the needed css and html only?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to recreate a similar scenario in the this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/josangel555/5ahd8qbb/)

Please check this solves the issue. I am doing this with the assumption that once the page is loaded, the left `div` height won't change. If it does, you have to write more Javascript to look for the changes and adjust the right `div` height;

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS Tables (`display: table`) to solve your problem.

Here are the basics.
I simplified the code you provided to make it easier for others to follow.

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: separate;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.col {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 30px;
}
.content {
  background: #EEE;
  width: 960px;
}
.list {
  background: #BBB;
  width: 316px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col content">
      <h1>Episode 01</h1>
      <!-- Your Video goes here -->
      <p><strong>This column has an automatic height. The other column's height will have the same height as this column</strong></p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col list">
      <h2>Andere Episoden:</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Episode 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Episode 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Episode 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to set a relative-positioned wrapper around both columns and set the position of the right column to be fixed.

```
/* solution */
#wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1040px; 
}

#right {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 380px;
}

#episodenbox1 {
  width: 340px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```css
#episodenbox {
  margin-top: 62px;
  width: 960px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: auto;
}
#titelbox {
  width: 960px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
#titelbox p {
  margin-left: 6px;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 50px;
}
#thumbnail {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 12px;
  width: 632px;
  height: auto;
}
#thumbnail p {
  width: 616px;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 19px;
  margin: 0px 6px 6px 6px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#episodenimg {
  width: 620px;
  height: 349px;
  display: block;
  margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}
#untertitelbox {
  margin-left: 12px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  float: left;
  width: 316px;
  height: 40px;
}
#untertitelbox p {
  margin-left: 6px;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 19px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 5px;
}
#episodenbox1 {
  margin-left: 12px;
  float: left;
  width: 316px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
#episode1 {
  float: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 316px;
  height: 68px;
}
#episode1 img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 56px;
  display: block;
  margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}
#episode1 p {
  margin-left: 112px;
  margin-top: -62px;
  color: #000000;
}
#episode2 {
  float: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 316px;
  height: 68px;
}
#episode2 img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 56px;
  display: block;
  margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}
#episode2 p {
  margin-left: 112px;
  margin-top: -62px;
  color: #000000;
}
#episode3 {
  margin-top: 3px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 316px;
  height: 68px;
}
#episode3 img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 56px;
  display: block;
  margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}
#episode3 p {
  margin-left: 112px;
  margin-top: -62px;
  color: #000000;
}
#episode4 {
  margin-top: 3px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 316px;
  height: 68px;
}
#episode4 img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 56px;
  display: block;
  margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}
#episode4 p {
  margin-left: 112px;
  margin-top: -62px;
  color: #000000;
}
#episode5 {
  margin-top: 3px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 316px;
  height: 68px;
}
#episode5 img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 56px;
  display: block;
  margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}
#episode5 p {
  margin-left: 112px;
  margin-top: -62px;
  color: #000000;
}
#episode6 {
  margin-top: 3px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 316px;
  height: 68px;
}
#episode6 img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 56px;
  display: block;
  margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}
#episode6 p {
  margin-left: 112px;
  margin-top: -62px;
  color: #000000;
}
#episode7 {
  margin-top: 3px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 316px;
  height: 68px;
}
#episode7 img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 56px;
  display: block;
  margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}
#episode7 p {
  margin-left: 112px;
  margin-top: -62px;
  color: #000000;
}
#episode8 {
  margin-top: 3px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 316px;
  height: 68px;
}
#episode8 img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 56px;
  display: block;
  margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}
#episode8 p {
  margin-left: 112px;
  margin-top: -62px;
  color: #000000;
}
#episode9 {
  margin-top: 3px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 316px;
  height: 68px;
}
#episode9 img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 56px;
  display: block;
  margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}
#episode9 p {
  margin-left: 112px;
  margin-top: -62px;
  color: #000000;
}
#episode10 {
  margin-top: 3px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 316px;
  height: 68px;
}
#episode10 img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 56px;
  display: block;
  margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}
#episode10 p {
  margin-left: 112px;
  margin-top: -62px;
  color: #000000;
}
#episode11 {
  margin-top: 3px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 316px;
  height: 68px;
}
#episode11 img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 56px;
  display: block;
  margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}
#episode11 p {
  margin-left: 112px;
  margin-top: -62px;
  color: #000000;
}
#episode12 {
  margin-top: 3px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 316px;
  height: 68px;
}
#episode12 img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 56px;
  display: block;
  margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}
#episode12 p {
  margin-left: 112px;
  margin-top: -62px;
  color: #000000;
}
#episode13 {
  margin-top: 3px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 316px;
  height: 68px;
}
#episode13 img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 56px;
  display: block;
  margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}
#episode13 p {
  margin-left: 112px;
  margin-top: -62px;
  color: #000000;
}
#episode14 {
  margin-top: 3px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 316px;
  height: 68px;
}
#episode14 img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 56px;
  display: block;
  margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}
#episode14 p {
  margin-left: 112px;
  margin-top: -62px;
  color: #000000;
}
#episode1:hover {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}
#episode2:hover {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}
#episode3:hover {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}
#episode4:hover {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}
#episode5:hover {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}
#episode6:hover {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}
#episode7:hover {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}
#episode8:hover {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}
#episode9:hover {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}
#episode10:hover {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}
#episode11:hover {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}
#episode12:hover {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}
#episode13:hover {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}
#episode14:hover {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

/* solution */
#wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1040px; 
}

#right {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 380px;
}

#episodenbox1 {
  width: 340px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left">
    <div id="titelbox">
      <p>Episode 01: Begegnung</p>
    </div>
    <div id="thumbnail">
      <img id="episodenimg" src="Episode%2001.png">
      <p>Aus einem unterirdischen Forschungslabor bricht ein Mutant in Gestalt eines jungen M&auml;dchens aus und t&ouml;tet dabei 23 Sicherheitsleute. Die beiden Teenager Yuka und Kohta treffen am Strand auf den Mutanten, der durch den Streifschuss am Kopf
        aber offenbar sein Ged&auml;chtnis verloren hat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <div id="untertitelbox">
      <p>Andere Episoden:</p>
    </div>
    <div id="episodenbox1">
      <a href="Episode%2002.html">
        <div id="episode2">
          <img src="Episode%2002.png">
          <p>Episode 02: Vernichtung</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="Episode%2003.html">
        <div id="episode3">
          <img src="Episode%2003.png">
          <p>Episode 03: Im Innersten</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="Episode%2004.html">
        <div id="episode4">
          <img src="Episode%2004.png">
          <p>Episode 04: Aufeinandertreffen</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="Episode%2005.html">
        <div id="episode5">
          <img src="Episode%2005.png">
          <p>Episode 05: Empfang</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="Episode%2006.html">
        <div id="episode6">
          <img src="Episode%2006.png">
          <p>Episode 06: Herzensw&auml;rme</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="Episode%2007.html">
        <div id="episode7">
          <img src="Episode%2007.png">
          <p>Episode 07: Zuf&auml;llige Begegnung</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="Episode%2008.html">
        <div id="episode8">
          <img src="Episode%2008.png">
          <p>Episode 08: Beginn</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="Episode%2009.html">
        <div id="episode9">
          <img src="Episode%2009.png">
          <p>Episode 09: Sch&ouml;ne Erinnerung</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="Episode%2010.html">
        <div id="episode10">
          <img src="Episode%2010.png">
          <p>Episode 10: S&auml;ugling</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="Episode%2010,5.html">
        <div id="episode11">
          <img src="Episode%2010,5.png">
          <p>Episode 10,5: Regenschauer</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="Episode%2011.html">
        <div id="episode12">
          <img src="Episode%2011.png">
          <p>Episode 11: Vermischung</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="Episode%2012.html">
        <div id="episode13">
          <img src="Episode%2012.png">
          <p>Episode 12: Taumeln</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="Episode%2013.html">
        <div id="episode14">
          <img src="Episode%2013.png">
          <p>Episode 13: Erleuchtung</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This solution is not responsive but your original code isn't either. In order to make it responsive you'll have to add `@media` queries so the absolute positioning will be only applied if the right column doesn't cover the left container.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for javascript, tables of fixed heights. You can also do it with flex-boxes.

If you want to do it this way you need to wrap the `<div>`s you want the scroll in an extra div, let's call it `#scroll`. Relatively position it's parent and absolutely position `#scroll`. The parent wont have a height so it will just expand (i.e. flex) to the remaining space withouth stretching the wrapper/container. By applying `top: 0; bottom: 0;` to `#scroll` you now have a div of the desired height and can force its contents to scroll.

```css
#episodenbox {
    margin-top: 62px;
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: auto;
}

#titelbox {
    width: 960px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#titelbox p {
    margin-left: 6px;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
}

#thumbnail {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 12px;
    width: 632px;
    height: auto;
}

#thumbnail p {
    width: 616px;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 19px;
    margin: 0px 6px 6px 6px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#episodenimg {
    width: 620px;
    height: 349px;
    display: block;
    margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

#untertitelbox {
    margin-left: 12px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    float: left;
    width: 316px;
    height: 40px;
}

#untertitelbox p {
    margin-left: 6px;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 19px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 5px;
}

#episodenbox1 {
    margin-left: 12px;
    float: left;
    width: 316px;
    /* Remove the following line*/
    /* overflow: scroll; */
}

#episode1 {
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 316px;
    height: 68px;
}

#episode1 img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 56px;
    display: block;
    margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

#episode1 p {
    margin-left: 112px;
    margin-top: -62px;
    color: #000000;
}

#episode2 {
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 316px;
    height: 68px;
}

#episode2 img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 56px;
    display: block;
    margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

#episode2 p {
    margin-left: 112px;
    margin-top: -62px;
    color: #000000;
}

#episode3 {
    margin-top: 3px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 316px;
    height: 68px;
}

#episode3 img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 56px;
    display: block;
    margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

#episode3 p {
    margin-left: 112px;
    margin-top: -62px;
    color: #000000;
}

#episode4 {
    margin-top: 3px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 316px;
    height: 68px;
}

#episode4 img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 56px;
    display: block;
    margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

#episode4 p {
    margin-left: 112px;
    margin-top: -62px;
    color: #000000;
}

#episode5 {
    margin-top: 3px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 316px;
    height: 68px;
}

#episode5 img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 56px;
    display: block;
    margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

#episode5 p {
    margin-left: 112px;
    margin-top: -62px;
    color: #000000;
}

#episode6 {
    margin-top: 3px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 316px;
    height: 68px;
}

#episode6 img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 56px;
    display: block;
    margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

#episode6 p {
    margin-left: 112px;
    margin-top: -62px;
    color: #000000;
}

#episode7 {
    margin-top: 3px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 316px;
    height: 68px;
}

#episode7 img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 56px;
    display: block;
    margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

#episode7 p {
    margin-left: 112px;
    margin-top: -62px;
    color: #000000;
}

#episode8 {
    margin-top: 3px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 316px;
    height: 68px;
}

#episode8 img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 56px;
    display: block;
    margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

#episode8 p {
    margin-left: 112px;
    margin-top: -62px;
    color: #000000;
}

#episode9 {
    margin-top: 3px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 316px;
    height: 68px;
}

#episode9 img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 56px;
    display: block;
    margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

#episode9 p {
    margin-left: 112px;
    margin-top: -62px;
    color: #000000;
}

#episode10 {
    margin-top: 3px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 316px;
    height: 68px;
}

#episode10 img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 56px;
    display: block;
    margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

#episode10 p {
    margin-left: 112px;
    margin-top: -62px;
    color: #000000;
}

#episode11 {
    margin-top: 3px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 316px;
    height: 68px;
}

#episode11 img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 56px;
    display: block;
    margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

#episode11 p {
    margin-left: 112px;
    margin-top: -62px;
    color: #000000;
}

#episode12 {
    margin-top: 3px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 316px;
    height: 68px;
}

#episode12 img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 56px;
    display: block;
    margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

#episode12 p {
    margin-left: 112px;
    margin-top: -62px;
    color: #000000;
}

#episode13 {
    margin-top: 3px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 316px;
    height: 68px;
}

#episode13 img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 56px;
    display: block;
    margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

#episode13 p {
    margin-left: 112px;
    margin-top: -62px;
    color: #000000;
}

#episode14 {
    margin-top: 3px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 316px;
    height: 68px;
}

#episode14 img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 56px;
    display: block;
    margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

#episode14 p {
    margin-left: 112px;
    margin-top: -62px;
    color: #000000;
}

#episode1:hover {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#episode2:hover {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#episode3:hover {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#episode4:hover {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#episode5:hover {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#episode6:hover {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#episode7:hover {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#episode8:hover {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#episode9:hover {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#episode10:hover {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#episode11:hover {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#episode12:hover {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#episode13:hover {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

#episode14:hover {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

/* The above I copied from your question. I've removed one line and added what follows */ 
#wrapper{
 display: flex;
}
#right{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}
#untertitelbox{
 flex: 0 0 auto;
}
#episodenbox1{
 flex: 1;
 position: relative;
}
#scroll{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'> <!-- Added -->
<div id="left">
                            <div id="titelbox">
                                <p>Episode 01: Begegnung</p>
                            </div>
                            <div id="thumbnail">
                                <img id="episodenimg" src="Episode%2001.png">
                                <p>Aus einem unterirdischen Forschungslabor bricht ein Mutant in Gestalt eines jungen M&auml;dchens aus und t&ouml;tet dabei 23 Sicherheitsleute. Die beiden Teenager Yuka und Kohta treffen am Strand auf den Mutanten, der durch den Streifschuss am Kopf aber offenbar sein Ged&auml;chtnis verloren hat.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="right">
                        <div id="untertitelbox">
                            <p>Andere Episoden:</p>
                        </div>
                            <div id="episodenbox1">
                              <div id='scroll'> <!-- Added -->
                                
                                <a href="Episode%2002.html"><div id="episode2">
                                    <img src="Episode%2002.png">
                                    <p>Episode 02: Vernichtung</p>
                                </div></a>
                                <a href="Episode%2003.html"><div id="episode3">
                                    <img src="Episode%2003.png">
                                    <p>Episode 03: Im Innersten</p>
                                </div></a>
                                <a href="Episode%2004.html"><div id="episode4">
                                    <img src="Episode%2004.png">
                                    <p>Episode 04: Aufeinandertreffen</p>
                                </div></a>
                                <a href="Episode%2005.html"><div id="episode5">
                                    <img src="Episode%2005.png">
                                    <p>Episode 05: Empfang</p>
                                </div></a>
                                <a href="Episode%2006.html"><div id="episode6">
                                    <img src="Episode%2006.png">
                                    <p>Episode 06: Herzensw&auml;rme</p>
                                </div></a>
                                <a href="Episode%2007.html"><div id="episode7">
                                    <img src="Episode%2007.png">
                                    <p>Episode 07: Zuf&auml;llige Begegnung</p>
                                </div></a>
                                <a href="Episode%2008.html"><div id="episode8">
                                    <img src="Episode%2008.png">
                                    <p>Episode 08: Beginn</p>
                                </div></a>
                                <a href="Episode%2009.html"><div id="episode9">
                                    <img src="Episode%2009.png">
                                    <p>Episode 09: Sch&ouml;ne Erinnerung</p>
                                </div></a>
                                <a href="Episode%2010.html"><div id="episode10">
                                    <img src="Episode%2010.png">
                                    <p>Episode 10: S&auml;ugling</p>
                                </div></a>
                                <a href="Episode%2010,5.html"><div id="episode11">
                                    <img src="Episode%2010,5.png">
                                    <p>Episode 10,5: Regenschauer</p>
                                </div></a>
                                <a href="Episode%2011.html"><div id="episode12">
                                    <img src="Episode%2011.png">
                                    <p>Episode 11: Vermischung</p>
                                </div></a>
                                <a href="Episode%2012.html"><div id="episode13">
                                    <img src="Episode%2012.png">
                                    <p>Episode 12: Taumeln</p>
                                </div></a>
                                <a href="Episode%2013.html"><div id="episode14">
                                    <img src="Episode%2013.png">
                                    <p>Episode 13: Erleuchtung</p>
                                </div></a>
                                </div> <!-- Added: end of scroll div -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
  </div> <!-- Added: end of wrapper div -->
```